# How to set default system Backcolor?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I designed a window that has the following attribute regarding the backcolor:

```
$window.Backcolor = "White"
```

When I added buttons they have a white backcolor by default from the window setting above and thats my issue here. How can I set the backcolor of the buttons to the default system color instead? I want them to look like the default Windows style.

Here is the diffenrece between how I want the backcolor of the buttons after setting the backcolor of the window to white and how they actually look like after changing the window backcolor:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying different things I found out that the following attribute solves the problem:

```
$button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Backcolor` of the button to the `Backcolor` of the form before you change the latter.

```
$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Text = 'button 1'
...
$button.Backcolor = $window.Backcolor

$window.Controls.Add($button)

$window.Backcolor = 'White'
```

Comment: This is a smart approach, but unfortunately the color of the buttons is then straight gray and not gradient gray as the system default style like in my screenshot above ...